# Show that $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^n \frac {x^2+n} {n^2}$, $x \in \mathbb R$, converges uniformly on every bounded interval

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that  $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^n \frac {x^2+n} {n^2}, x \in \mathbb R$ converge uniformly on every bounded interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$.

I've already shown that the series does **not** converge absolutely for $x \in \mathbb R$. I guess, I proved this to conclude that the series **doesn't have a majorant series** which would imply that the series converged uniformly (viewed as a series of functions) and absolutely as a tradional series for $x \in \mathbb R$.

I know I must show that the $s_k = \sum^{k}_{n=1} (-1)^n \frac {x^2+n} {n^2}$ converge uniformly, but I haven't had any luck in showing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simpler the better...
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant N}(-1)^n \frac {x^2+n} {n^2}
=
x^2\cdot\sum_{n\geqslant N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}
+
\sum_{n\geqslant N}\frac{(-1)^n}n
$$
**Edit:** Both series in the RHS are [alternating series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) hence the absolute value of a given rest is bounded by [the absolute value of the first term in the rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums), that is,
$$
\left|\sum_{n\geqslant N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\leqslant\frac1{N^2},\qquad
\left|\sum_{n\geqslant N}\frac{(-1)^n}n\right|\leqslant\frac1N.
$$

Comment: So I know the series converges for $x \in \mathbb R$ (I've just proved this myself). I can write the sum-function $s(x) := \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^n \frac {x^2+n} {n^2}$ with domain $\mathbb R$. Now given $\epsilon > 0$ I want to find $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|s_k(x)=\sum^{k}_{n=1} (-1)^n \frac {x^2+n} {n^2} - s(x)| < \epsilon$ for $k \ge N$ and $x \in I \ \ (a < x < b)$. How can I find this $N$ from your answer ?

Comment: By bounding the absolute value of the first rest by $1/N^2$ and the absolute value of the second rest by $1/N$ hence the absolute value of the whole LHS is  at most $x^2/N^2+1/N$. On $|x|\leqslant C$, this is at most $C^2/N^2+1/N$, which can be made less than $\varepsilon$, for every $\varepsilon\gt0$, by a suitable choice of $N$.

Comment: How do you show such a bound holds ?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: I know $(-1)^n / n$ converges, but how do I show $(-1)^n / n^2$ also converges ?

Comment: You mean, the series? Well, either you see $\sum\limits_n(-1)^n/n^2$ as an alternating series, hence a convergent one (as written explicitely in my post), or you remember that $\sum\limits_n1/n^2$ converges hence $\sum\limits_n(-1)^n/n^2$ converges *absolutely*.

Comment: @did you have shown that $s_k$ is bounded, but why does that imply that $|s_k-s(x)|$ is bounded by something that is less than $/epsilon$ for sufficiently large k?

Comment: @Zslice "you have shown that sk is bounded" No.

Answer (score -2):

We have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\ln2$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Hence $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi^2x^2}{12}-\ln2$$